# Starting a Column from the center of its parent

Tags: flutter, center

I am trying to implement a Column within a parent, but the first child of the Column should be centered vertically within the Column's parent, by using MainAxisAlignment.center the whole Column will be centered and if I have more than one child in the Column, the first child won't be in the center.

Here is what i have tried.

```
child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 146,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text('11:06',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 70,
                                  )),
                              Icon(Icons.restart_alt),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Here is what i got.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g5eu.png)
As you see the text is not in the center because the icon pushes it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some padding. I am not aware of a way to get the size of the parent and do like 50% of it like in CSS so you have to keep that in mind. However you can make calculations relative to the viewport height with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that I have some ways to manipulate the outcome with padding or with other methods, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your column in another column containing an `Expanded` widget followed by your column, also wrapped in an Expanded widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Align` inside `Stack` (not perfect, still needs adjustment).

```
CircleAvatar(
...
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: const [
      Text('11:06', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 70)),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 0.4),
        child: Icon(Icons.restart_alt),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```